# Meaning of the term "Not a Polynomial"

Tags: polynomials, approximation

I was reading the following link on the "Universal Approximation Theorem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) and came across the following statement:

[image]

I am really confused by what this statement means : *a continuous function* "sigma" is **not a polynomial**

If "sigma" is not a polynomial - what else can "sigma" be? Is there any "undesirable connotation" associated with a function being "a polynomial"? Is there any "desirable" connotation associated with a function being "not a polynomial"?

Thanks!

Comment: "If "sigma" is not a polynomial - what else can "sigma" be? "  What do you mean?  It could be any other continuous function.  Are you asking whether there are other (continuous) functions other than polynomials?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a polynomial? The statement has a previously added stipulation that sigma is continuous, so being not a polynomial in this sense means being any continuous function which is not a polynomial

Comment: A polynomial is a very special function which is infinitely differentiable, with only a finite number of non-zero derivatives. A "non-polynomial" is any other function.